# error: use of deleted function ‘pQueue::pQueue(const pQueue&)’ note: <func> is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and am encountering this error while building the code. Found some answers online but am unable to understand them. Can someone please explain what this error means and how to resolve it in simple terms?

For reference, I'm attaching the code snippets. These snippets are part of a project, so might miss out on a few details.

file.cpp

```
#include "File.h"
using namespace std;

pQueue::pQueue()
{
  std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, Category*>> q;
}

pQueue::~pQueue()
{
}

void queueWork(std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, Category*>> q, int action, Category* data)
{
  q.emplace(make_pair(action, data));
}

void doWork(std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, Category*>> q)
{
  while (true)
  {
    std::pair<int, Category*> queueElement;
    queueElement = q.top();
    Category* data = queueElement.second;
    // Perform some operation, get return value
    q.pop();
  }
}
```

file.h

```
#pragma once
#include <queue>
#include <thread>

class pQueue
{
public:
  pQueue();
  ~pQueue();

 void queueWork(std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, Category*>> q, int action, Category* data);

private:
  void doWork(std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, Category*>> q);
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "File.h"
bool function(Category* data)
{
    if (data)
    {
        // Will set action values later
        auto action = 1;
        pQueue::queueWork(Queue, action, data);

        // TODO: Implement getResult function to get the return value
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: On which instance is `pQueue::queueWork(Queue, action, data);` supposed to be working? `queueWork` is a non-`static` member function which is not implemented, just like the other member function, `doWork`. You've implemented two free functions instead of the member functions you've declared.

Comment: Pouring on the salt, it also takes it `q` by *value*, so `queueWork` will gleefully queue an item into a priority queue that is thereafter going to go poof.

Comment: The function signature, where you are passing an entire data structure (priority_queue) by value has a hint of trying to use Java or C# or similar language as a model in writing C++ code.  This is one obvious case where you will get burned by this (assuming this is where you got the idea of passing parameters this way).

Comment: Thank you everyone, will work on the solutions provided :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the rule of zero here (see [rule of 3 and rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three))

```
class pQueue {
public:
  void queueWor(int action, Category* data);

private:
  void doWork();

  std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, Category*>> q;
};
```

The compiler generated destructor, copy, and move will be correct and sufficient in this case.

Note that in your current implementation `q` is not a member variable, instead it is simply a local variable that only exists within the scope of your constructor.